# Minimum area bounded between two curves

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization, area, maxima-minima

What is the minimum area bounded between the curve $ y = \dfrac{x^2}4 $ and $y=ax+9$, where $a$ is some real number.

I tried to use application of derivative but not able to reach a final solution.

Comment: Just draw both functions and find a way to express the area between them as the difference of both integrals.

Comment: You should also mention the interval on which you are interested in minimizing this area, as this area would be infinite if considered on the whole real line.

Answer (score 1):

The line $y=ax+9$ will always lie above the parabola $y=\frac{x^2}4$, intersecting when

$$ax+9=\frac{x^2}4\implies x^2-4ax-36=0$$

at two points, $x_1$ and $x_2$, both dependent on $a$. (It's given that $a\in\mathbb R$, so the line is never vertical, hence there are two points of intersection.)

The area between the curves is then a function of $a$,

$$\operatorname{Area}(a)=\int_{x_1(a)}^{x_2(a)}\left((ax+9)-\frac{x^2}4\right)\,\mathrm dx$$

which can be minimized by applying the fundamental theorem of calculus. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Thanx !!! I did the same method. Is there any shortcut method ?

Comment: Faster than integration, you mean? I doubt it. But if you're interested in another method, you could look up "Archimedes parabolic segment area".